# Can I say "get into a mess of ..."?

Tags: word-usage

For example,

> So we can avoid getting into a mess of switching between different contexts.

If we can't say like that, how to express the equivalent meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time I've heard

> "get into a mess of"

Is in the idiom

> "Get into a mess of trouble"

Which is a bit "folksy" (Southern AME) and not appropriate for all contexts.

I would try

> We should avoid switching between contexts, which makes our project vastly more complicated.

or if you're using it as an explanation.

> So we can avoid the quagmire of context-switching

A quagmire is like a marsh or a bog, and is commonly used as a metaphor for complex situations that are difficult to get out of.

Other options:

> We should avoid switching contexts unless we want this project to fall apart.
>
> Context-switching would mess up this project, we should avoid it.

Comment: I think I should use `mess up` instead. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by "mess".

> so we don't get bogged down with different contexts.
>   so we don't get distracted by different contexts.
>   so we don't get sidelined by different contexts.